# Why has the boolean modifier created new vertices?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, vertices, topology

As you can see in object mode there are 4 vertices that have separated the front of the cartridge into multiple faces when I use boolean modifiers on cartridge.001. How can I fix this?  I imagine it has to do with good topology.

Here's the cartridge in object mode showing faces:

[image]

Here is the cartridge with the unwanted vertices:

[image]

Attached is the .blend

[image]

Comment: I think that holed-ngons are not currently supported. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48779/15140

Comment: Related also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74656/cant-disolve-edge-and-faces/74660#74660

Answer (score 2):

The topology you see in wireframe mode is real topology of your mesh if the modifiers were applied. The edges (and not vertices) are added because it is impossible in Blender (as far as i know) to have a face with an hole in it, with a connected vertex. To create a hole you need to create a cut to join the two edge loop of the new face.

The wireframe view can avoid to display some edges if the faces have the same normal, but for that you need to apply the modifiers, then go to *Edit Mode* and back to *Object Mode*.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I think once you apply the boolean modifiers you can fix it using limited dissolve.

Comment: Hm I tried working with it but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Is there a particular article on limited dissolve that would help?