# How do I get rid of these extra cuts when using Boolean?

Tags: modifiers

I'm a beginner to Blender, and I'm trying to create a container (as pictured)
to import as an OBJ file into Adobe Dimension.
[image: picture 1]
I realized after using the Boolean tool that there would be extra "cuts" to the object, resulting in (see other picture) a weird screen over the model when imported into Dimension. Any suggestions are helpful, thank you!
[image: dimension import]

Comment: I found this related question on the exchange. The problem seems to be exactly what the answer to that question outlined. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75568/why-has-the-boolean-modifier-created-new-vertices

Comment: A face can't have a hole in it, and a vertex can't be in the same face more than one time. This is why the operation automatically adds these edges.